# check if hWnd is a button

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to check if a hWnd is a button.

This code is for getting the hWnd:

```
public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);


public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
{
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
    try
    {
        EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
        EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
            listHandle.Free();
    }
    return result;
}
```

now I have to find out, which hWnd of the list is a button.
Thanks

Comment: Please define what you mean by "button"

Comment: Well, it seems that by your accepted answer your definition of button is *a window with the class name "Button"*. That's an exceptionally limited definition of button.

Comment: Why not use System.Windows.Automation?

Comment: To answer Raymond's question: There is **no** reason to not use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). There is one striking reason to go with UI Automation: It'll also allow you to identify controls, that aren't native Windows controls (e.g. buttons on a web page, button widgets built with toolkits like Qt or GTK, or WPF controls). The proposed solution will miss all of the aforementioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function "GetClassName" to find out the win32-class of the hwnd. For standard win32-buttons it will always be 'Button'. You may use it like this:

```
public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName,int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);

public static List<IntPtr> GetChildButtons(IntPtr parent)
{
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
    try
    {
        EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
        EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
            listHandle.Free();
    }
    return result
        .Where(x => {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
            GetClassName(x, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
            return buffer.ToString() == "Button";
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you quite sure it's not `BUTTON`? In any case, I'd say that the majority of button like things these days are not BUTTON windows.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#system and a short test with spy++ it's "Button". Of course this only works if the buttons are native, default win32-buttons...

Comment: Would have been good if We had the ATOM id for win32 Button. Then we could easily check integer against integer.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Buttons have the window class BUTTON. You could use the [GetClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to discover if a button is a button.

Note that nowadays many apps don't use windows controls, so there could be a button that doesn't use the BUTTON class. Some apps (web browsers for example or WPF apps) are even completely "owner drawed" and don't use any window control at all (other than the "container" window).

Once upon a time there was a very useful tool, Spy++, to check the windows. It was very useful to comprehend how the UI of programs were built. Mmmh... Still present in Visual Studio: on my machine (Visual Studio 2013): *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe*

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName,int nMaxCount);
```

Compare the class name with "Button"

Answer (score -1):

I wanted also to determine if a control was of a certain type; even though I am using cpp not c#.

Why I need to be able to determine control class? I have a series of classes representing each win32 control. They each can accept a hwnd in there overloaded constructor.

```
class Widget
{
 Widget(HWND widget = NULL);

 HWND widget; 
}

class Button extends Widget
{
 Button(HWND widget = NULL):
}
```

Problem arises if I pass a control of different class to Button. Now any operation I try on button will fail.

A solution would be to check the class name of the control we are passing. But that is O(n) in-efficient. Mark you, you never notice the in-efficiency. But in an ideal world we would check the integer ATOMS of the Button and control being passed. This would be O(n) efficient.

Sadly, I don't see where MSDN list the ATOM constants of there controls. Furthermore, I don't even know if ATOM(s) generated via RegisterClass are persistable. A portable solution is the following:

```
ATOM button_atom = 0;

HWND getButton(HWND widget,String expectedName)
{
    if(widget == NULL) return widget; // NULL is default value

    else if(button_atom != 0)
    {
    // if widget ATOM and button_atom are different, throw exception
    }

    else //if widget class name and expectedName are different, throw exception

    else // store wiget ATOM into button_atom

    return widget;
}
```

This way. We only do string comparison for the control once.